# jQuery plugin vertical align images setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a quick and simple plugin that vertical aligns images that I have used successfully in a number of websites although I am now working with a new CMS that automatically resizes the images which creates a delay in loading the resized images thus causing the plugin to return null for the height. This only happens on first load of the page.

I thought I could fix this with a timeout although this causes the parent.height to always return null.

```
//Vertically Allign Images
jQuery.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var $strip = jQuery(this);
            var ah = $strip.height();
            var ph = $strip.parent().height();
            alert('height = '+ah+' parent = '+ph);
            //height = 429 parent = null
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
            $strip.css('margin-top', mh);
        },1000);
    });

};
```

Comment: probably need to do it within `$(document).ready` to avoid delay

Comment: I call this plugin with: $(".image").vAlign(); inside of the document ready. Or does the plugin need to go inside a document ready also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the setTimeout function, `this` is the `window` object (the setTimeout function runs in global scope), and so `$(this).parent()` is an empty jQuery object (because `window` has no parent).

It would be best if you can load the images using JavaScript so that you can assign a `load` event handler to do the vertical alignment, something like:

```
jQuery.fn.vAlign = function () {
    return this.bind('load', function () {
        // do alignment
    });
};

$('<img />')
    .vAlign() // call before assigning src
    .appendTo('body')
    .attr('src', '...');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you lose the context of the jQuery function when you fire setTimeout.  Try defining your variables in the global scope and then calling `setTimeout`.

Either way, this doesn't seem to me to be the best way to vertically align images -- is there a reason you're doing this with JS rather than using the `line-height` or `vertical-align` CSS properties?

Comment: I would prefer to use CSS but I didn't think it was possible. Vertical-align only works across all browsers if its inside a table cell. 
I will give line-height a test in the different browsers

Comment: Vertical align should work across most browsers if you define a static height for the container element.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to even in ff. In my HTML I have:
<a href="#"><img src="foo" /></a>

CSS:
a {display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;}

a img {display:block;}

Comment: Ah-ha :)  You have to actually assign the `vertical-align` property to the element you want vertically aligned.  So it would be `a img {vertical-align: bottom}`

Comment: Sorry I made a typo earlier and wrote bottom, I mean middle. 

I have tried as you suggest but it still doesn't work. I use a reset css that clears all browser defaults and maybe this is causing it. 

I have just read here that you need display:table-cell on the containing element, although this will not work in IE7 and below